# ffmpeg-python error, cannot load mp4 encoder

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mp4, encoder

This error came when I just try a simple demo from the page of ffmpeg-python:

```
import ffmpeg
stream = ffmpeg.input('human_face.mp4')
stream = ffmpeg.hflip(stream)
stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, 'new_human_face.mp4')
ffmpeg.run(stream)
```

And the output goes like:

```
...
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'human_face.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.49.100
  Duration: 00:00:12.45, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 742 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (mp4v / 0x7634706D), none, 256x256, 741 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 10240 tbn, 10240 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:0. Default encoder for format mp4 (codec mpeg4) is probably disabled or this build of ffmpeg does not include that codec. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/tristan_jia/workspace/py3.6/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ffmpeg/_run.py", line 325, in run
    raise Error('ffmpeg', out, err)
```

I think the most important log is:"**Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:0. Default encoder for format mp4 (codec mpeg4) is probably disabled or this build of ffmpeg does not include that codec. Please choose an encoder manually.**"

I've reinstalled the ffmpeg package but the error remains.

---

Appended 1:
Thanks for the comment from @HernánAlarcón:

- **the version is 3.4.4.**
- **the output of `ffmpeg -encoders` is:**

```
(venv) tristan_jia@linux-ftbv:~/.../data> ffmpeg -encoders
ffmpeg version 3.4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (SUSE Linux)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --extra-cflags='-fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -g' --optflags='-fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -g' --disable-htmlpages --enable-pic --disable-stripping --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-gpl --disable-openssl --enable-avresample --enable-libcdio --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcelt --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-muxers --enable-demuxers --disable-encoders --disable-decoders --disable-decoder='mpeg4,h263,h264,hevc,vc1' --enable-encoder='apng,ass,ayuv,bmp,ffv1,ffvhuff,flac,gif,huffyuv,jpegls,libgsm,libmp3lame,libopenjpeg,libopus,libschroedinger,libspeex,libtheora,libtwolame,libvorbis,libvpx_vp8,libvpx_vp9,libwebp,libwebp_anim,mjpeg,mp2,mp2fixed,opus,pam,pbm,pcm_alaw,pcm_f32be,pcm_f32le,pcm_f64be,pcm_f64le,pcm_mulaw,pcm_s16be,pcm_s16be_planar,pcm_s16le,pcm_s16le_planar,pcm_s24be,pcm_s24le,pcm_s24le_planar,pcm_s32be,pcm_s32le,pcm_s32le_planar,pcm_s8,pcm_s8_planar,pcm_u16be,pcm_u16le,pcm_u24be,pcm_u24le,pcm_u32be,pcm_u32le,pcm_u8,pcx,pgm,pgmyuv,png,ppm,sgi,srt,ssa,sunrast,targa,text,tiff,v210,v308,v408,v410,vorbis,xbm,xwd,y41p,yuv4,zlib,' --enable-decoder='ac3,ansi,apng,ass,ayuv,bmp,dirac,exr,ffv1,ffvhuff,ffwavesynth,flac,gif,gsm,huffyuv,libcelt,libgsm,libopenjpeg,libopus,libschroedinger,libspeex,libvorbis,libvpx_vp8,libvpx_vp9,mjpeg,mpeg1video,mpeg2video,,mp1,mp1float,mp2,mp2float,mp3,mp3float,opus,pam,pbm,pcm_alaw,pcm_bluray,pcm_dvd,pcm_f32be,pcm_f32le,pcm_f64be,pcm_f64le,pcm_mulaw,pcm_s16be,pcm_s16be_planar,pcm_s16le,pcm_s16le_planar,pcm_s24be,pcm_s24le,pcm_s24le_planar,pcm_s32be,pcm_s32le,pcm_s32le_planar,pcm_s8,pcm_s8_planar,pcm_u16be,pcm_u16le,pcm_u24be,pcm_u24le,pcm_u32be,pcm_u32le,pcm_u8,pcx,pgm,pgmyuv,pgssub,png,ppm,rawvideo,sgi,srt,ssa,sunrast,targa,text,theora,tiff,v210,v210x,v308,v408,v410,vorbis,vp3,vp5,vp6,vp6a,vp6f,vp8,vp9,webp,xbm,xwd,y41p,yuv4,zlib,'
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Encoders:
 V..... = Video
 A..... = Audio
 S..... = Subtitle
 .F.... = Frame-level multithreading
 ..S... = Slice-level multithreading
 ...X.. = Codec is experimental
 ....B. = Supports draw_horiz_band
 .....D = Supports direct rendering method 1
 ------
 V..... apng                 APNG (Animated Portable Network Graphics) image
 V..... ayuv                 Uncompressed packed MS 4:4:4:4
 V..... bmp                  BMP (Windows and OS/2 bitmap)
 V.S... ffv1                 FFmpeg video codec #1
 VF.... ffvhuff              Huffyuv FFmpeg variant
 V..... gif                  GIF (Graphics Interchange Format)
 VF.... huffyuv              Huffyuv / HuffYUV
 VF.... libopenjpeg          OpenJPEG JPEG 2000 (codec jpeg2000)
 VF.... jpegls               JPEG-LS
 VFS... mjpeg                MJPEG (Motion JPEG)
 V..... pam                  PAM (Portable AnyMap) image
 V..... pbm                  PBM (Portable BitMap) image
 V..... pcx                  PC Paintbrush PCX image
 V..... pgm                  PGM (Portable GrayMap) image
 V..... pgmyuv               PGMYUV (Portable GrayMap YUV) image
 VF.... png                  PNG (Portable Network Graphics) image
 V..... ppm                  PPM (Portable PixelMap) image
 V..... sgi                  SGI image
 V..... sunrast              Sun Rasterfile image
 V..... targa                Truevision Targa image
 V..... libtheora            libtheora Theora (codec theora)
 VF.... tiff                 TIFF image
 V..... v210                 Uncompressed 4:2:2 10-bit
 V..... v308                 Uncompressed packed 4:4:4
 V..... v408                 Uncompressed packed QT 4:4:4:4
 V..... v410                 Uncompressed 4:4:4 10-bit
 V..... libvpx               libvpx VP8 (codec vp8)
 V..... libvpx-vp9           libvpx VP9 (codec vp9)
 V..... libwebp_anim         libwebp WebP image (codec webp)
 V..... libwebp              libwebp WebP image (codec webp)
 V..... xbm                  XBM (X BitMap) image
 V..... xwd                  XWD (X Window Dump) image
 V..... y41p                 Uncompressed YUV 4:1:1 12-bit
 V..... yuv4                 Uncompressed packed 4:2:0
 VF.... zlib                 LCL (LossLess Codec Library) ZLIB
 A..... flac                 FLAC (Free Lossless Audio Codec)
 A..... libgsm               libgsm GSM (codec gsm)
 A..... mp2                  MP2 (MPEG audio layer 2)
 A..... mp2fixed             MP2 fixed point (MPEG audio layer 2) (codec mp2)
 A..... libtwolame           libtwolame MP2 (MPEG audio layer 2) (codec mp2)
 A..... libmp3lame           libmp3lame MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3) (codec mp3)
 A..X.. opus                 Opus
 A..... libopus              libopus Opus (codec opus)
 A..... pcm_alaw             PCM A-law / G.711 A-law
 A..... pcm_f32be            PCM 32-bit floating point big-endian
 A..... pcm_f32le            PCM 32-bit floating point little-endian
 A..... pcm_f64be            PCM 64-bit floating point big-endian
 A..... pcm_f64le            PCM 64-bit floating point little-endian
 A..... pcm_mulaw            PCM mu-law / G.711 mu-law
 A..... pcm_s16be            PCM signed 16-bit big-endian
 A..... pcm_s16be_planar     PCM signed 16-bit big-endian planar
 A..... pcm_s16le            PCM signed 16-bit little-endian
 A..... pcm_s16le_planar     PCM signed 16-bit little-endian planar
 A..... pcm_s24be            PCM signed 24-bit big-endian
 A..... pcm_s24le            PCM signed 24-bit little-endian
 A..... pcm_s24le_planar     PCM signed 24-bit little-endian planar
 A..... pcm_s32be            PCM signed 32-bit big-endian
 A..... pcm_s32le            PCM signed 32-bit little-endian
 A..... pcm_s32le_planar     PCM signed 32-bit little-endian planar
 A..... pcm_s8               PCM signed 8-bit
 A..... pcm_s8_planar        PCM signed 8-bit planar
 A..... pcm_u16be            PCM unsigned 16-bit big-endian
 A..... pcm_u16le            PCM unsigned 16-bit little-endian
 A..... pcm_u24be            PCM unsigned 24-bit big-endian
 A..... pcm_u24le            PCM unsigned 24-bit little-endian
 A..... pcm_u32be            PCM unsigned 32-bit big-endian
 A..... pcm_u32le            PCM unsigned 32-bit little-endian
 A..... pcm_u8               PCM unsigned 8-bit
 A..... libspeex             libspeex Speex (codec speex)
 A..X.. vorbis               Vorbis
 A..... libvorbis            libvorbis (codec vorbis)
 S..... ssa                  ASS (Advanced SubStation Alpha) subtitle (codec ass)
 S..... ass                  ASS (Advanced SubStation Alpha) subtitle
 S..... srt                  SubRip subtitle (codec subrip)
 S..... text                 Raw text subtitle
'''
```

Comment: What it the ffmpeg version (`ffmpeg -version`)? What encoders does it have (`ffmpeg -encoders`)? Do you see the same error if you run ffmpeg directly?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón Thanks for your help. No, the returns of these two commands are good. The version is 3.4.4. and I've appened the return with ```ffmpeg -encoder``` to the question.

Comment: I meant that if you see the same error when you run `ffmpeg -i ...` because, as the error message says, your ffmpeg does not seem to have the `mpeg4` encoder. My ffmpeg shows this: `V.S... mpeg4                MPEG-4 part 2`. Note that the ffmpeg output says `--disable-decoder='mpeg4,...`. I wonder if that has something to do. But anyway, your ffmpeg version is outdated. The latest release seems to be `4.3.1`. I would recommend to upgrade it and see if that works.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón Thanks for your advice. It works after I reinstalled the latest version with snap.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help from @Hernán, I recognize that on OpenSuse, if you just use `sudo zypper in ffmpeg` it'll install an outdated version of ffmpeg. So I removed this package and reinstall it with snap ([instruction](https://snapcraft.io/install/ffmpeg/opensuse)). And then it worked totally fine. Hope that's helpful for other people.